# timeout on large file (10-300Mo) upload using Firebase react-JS google-cloud-storage

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

I started a WebApp in Firebase with the aim to upload files (10-300Mo) on google storage and run ML on the content.

I used react-JS as the client to create a form to upload files and used firebase module ('firebase/storage') the resumable upload as described in here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files):

`var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/' + file.name).put(file, metadata);`

the upload works well on windows 10 but on iOS (iPhone, iPad) it hangs up and returns a times out after ~5-10mins. It is very reproductible. The time and bytes transferred to time-out depends on network (WiFi or 4G).

I tried to debug the .put() function but could not figure out why after few chunks the resumable upload times out on iOS and not on Windows.

Did anyone encounter the same issue? Any hint for debugging or solving the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since the only different factor seems to be the device where the code is executed, I'd say that the problem is relying in the code or at a device limitation.

I think the best would be to review if this is happening at different devide versions or in all of them.

Greetings.

Comment: Hi Sergio. thanks for your answer! i did test on several devices (2 iPhones, 1 iPad - Chrome and Safari and my windowd laptop - Chrome and Edge).  iOS times out but not on Windows. I tried several packet length, so it's not about the individual HTTP PUT but it seems there is a timeout at 60s from the time I start the upload...did you see this already in your experience?

Comment: I've seen the request timeout at 60s too. It's recommend to [retry timed out requests](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/resumable-uploads#practices) as a best practice, and for the case of the resumable updates you can try to modify the chunk sizes as mentioned in this [github thread](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/issues/74#issuecomment-602487082)

Comment: Thanks again Sergio for the quick answer. it is not the invidual PUT request to GCS that times out, but rather the "main loop". I had done test with smaller chunk size and it did not help (I used 2Mo on ADSL - the put takes 20s). still the first PUT that starts after 60s since the beginning of the whole upload will hang and eventualy timeout after 10min. it does not happen on windows. yesterday I tried on iOS with Firefox, Edge and DuckDuckGO and they have the same behavior...there is something fundamental that I am missing here...

Comment: I'm not fully aware of such limitations, from my point of view I see that Cloud Storage might be having a different behavior due to these limitations that it seems we are missing, such seems to be at the device level due to your tests.